# User social network integration in external mobile library

Tags: android, ios, facebook, architecture

I'm developing a library for mobile apps.
**The library is a wrapper** to my web API (REST), and provide several objects in order to facilitate the implementation in code.

My API required social integration (Facebook, for example) - in my stand-alone app, the app is asking Facebook for permissions and send the token to the server using the API.

### Assumptions:

1. The apps, that going to integrate my library is already require social integration from it's users.
2. The developers who going to use this library, knows that the library require social integration, and willing to add my library required permissions to their apps.

### Questions:

(My question is partially **architectural** and partially about **best/common practice**)

1. Can I use the host apps token to interact with the social network? (for example, posting an image in behalf of user).

   1.1. If the answer is **"yes"**, is there any limitations? Can I later access this data from server (without the host app secret key)?

   1.2. If the answer in **"no"**, can my library ask for permission? (i.e. open Facebook permissions dialog in the host app)

And, is there any **other/better solution** for this problem?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use app generated token to interact with facebook. token depend on user, app, and permissions. so for same user but different app it will be different token. 
to upload images and post on walls you need to set permission on time of token generation and/or time of app generation on facebook.

last thing when you post make sure setup privacy and every token expires in 60days though you can generate long term tokens too.

Comment: Thanks, AFAIK I will not be able to access the posted images without the host app secret key.
So posting is easy - but what about collect later usage data from graph-api about those uploaded posts?

Comment: your are right but good part is every post will return you post id for every kind of post but you can access these post only using either owner token or App token and might be if its public post and you authorized that app on your account. you can user your token to access public posts data.