# Using user access token with another app id

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a library for mobile apps. The library is a wrapper to my web API (REST), and provide several objects in order to facilitate the implementation in code.

My API required social integration (Facebook, for example) - in my stand-alone app, the app is asking Facebook for permissions and send the token to the server using the API.

### Problem:

When user is use the host app (the app that use my library) and the app use the library API to post something on Facebook, I'm getting from the host app the users access token and the post id.

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448147/user-social-network-integration-in-external-mobile-library) (comment by [m-farhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1112691/m-farhan)) - he says that when I have the user token, and post id - I can access the post even without the host app secret.

I tried connecting facebook with my app secret, set the user access token and than using the post_id, fetch the post data - but I've got the following error:

> Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument

### Question:

Is there any way to access the post data (it's not a public post) using the user access token and the post id from my app, that is different from the app used to actually made the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user access token has some validity. Moreover, you can use the **App Access Token** (of the app used to create the post) with the **post-id** to get the post details.

Your app access token is `AppId|App_Secret` and it never expires. Or you can also generate this with-

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
  client_id={app-id}
  &client_secret={app-secret}
  &grant_type=client_credentials
```

(Beware, don't expose your app access token, its just like a password to your application.)

[Reference- App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens)

I'm not sure how are you fetching the post data, but its a simple `GET` request to `/post-id` using that app token. Eg: https://graph.facebook.com/Post-ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN